# Database : Table and mappings for a Matrix style table

Tags: database, spring, postgresql, database-design

I am working on a Spring-MVC using Postgres application in which I am trying to do a report generation form. Now, for this, I have to save the data for the form. But, the report has this matrix kind of part, which I don't know how to realize. Sure I can do it, but I want something optimized. 
[image]

As you can see from the image, on left side, there are fields and each field has different values to be inserted as indicated.

As of now, I was able to come up only one Table as Parts and its class is mentioned below. But as each variable in the class will have 6 values, it will require me to create 6 tables and have some mapping. I want to avoid that. What can I do?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "containment")
public class Containment {

    @Id
    @Column(name="containment_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,generator = "containment_gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "containment_gen",sequenceName = "containment_seq")
    private Long containmentId;

    @Column(name = "parts_at_plant")
    private String partsAtPlant;

    @Column(name = "parts_at_logistics")
    private String partsAtLogistics;



}
```

I am creating class, not writing database-tables directly. If someone wants to see above in SQL code, I am more than happy to write it. Thank you.

Comment: Looks like a variant on the EAV problem.

Comment: @CraigRinger : Can you tell me what I can do about it?? I have no idea what you just said but I am looking up on net for it.

Comment: I'm talking about the Entity-Attribute-Value (anti)pattern, and alternatives to it like storing json / xml documents in the DB. It's an approach typically used as a last resort when you have to model a dynamic table

Comment: @CraigRinger : I found the model you are talking about, any suggestions on how I can implement them using Hibernate?

Comment: @CraigRinger : Can you tell me how I can use hstore to solve this problem. Thanks a lot. :-)